# dl.bintray 502 Bad Gateway Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, bintray

This is my error

Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-base/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

My gradle is online

I tried some possibilities upgrade and down grade version of dependencies.

```
repositories {
maven {
    url "http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
}
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven Central()
```

}

which dependencies should added to resolve this issues?...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you don't need to put:

```
maven {
  url "http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
}
```

If you have included `mavenCentral()` then it will be enough. Otherwise, you have to include `mavenCentral()` to `repositories`

Comment: error is solved by updating some gradles version and by adding mavencentral().

Answer (score 0):

JFrog Bintray is Deprecated. Below is the complete details.
https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

Can you please check with the "microsoft azure mobile" organization to which path they have migrated the artifacts. The reason is before JFrog Bintray Deprecation the "microsoft azure mobile" organization might have moved the data/artifacts to different location.

Comment: But there are 2 different projects in one project it's running properly.while another gives the error

Comment: Is the issue is for only one artifacts? does the same artifact is successfully pulled by another project?

Comment: yes gives error in one project while both gradles files are same